# Converting DateTime obtained from graph call to time zone set on the PC where scripts run

Tags: powershell, datetime, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a powershell script where i perform the call to microsoft.graph.callRecords ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)).

I get the parameters startDateTime and endDateTimes and i would like to transfer it to italian time zone, the problem is that italian time zone is UTC+1 for 6 months a year and UTC+2 for the other 6 months so i would like to get the TimeZoneId directly from the machine where the script is running (which updated automatically).

In particular i am getting each field returned by the graph call and creating a powershell object out of it. I would like to convert the above mentioned *DateTimes field to the local timezone in that moment.

This is what i tried, but it is not working.

```
$participant | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "startDateTime"             -value [TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(([DateTime]$usersession.startDateTime), 'UTC', (Get-TimeZone).toString()).ToString()
```

Both `$usersession` and `$participant` should be powershell objects.

Do you guys have any advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Get-TimeZone).toString()` returns the `DisplayName` property:

```
PS> Get-TimeZone

Id                         : GMT Standard Time
DisplayName                : (UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
StandardName               : GMT Standard Time
DaylightName               : GMT Daylight Time
BaseUtcOffset              : 00:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : True


PS> (Get-TimeZone).ToString()
(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
```

but `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` wants a timezone Id (see [ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime, String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=net-5.0#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId_System_DateTime_System_String_System_String_):

> **public static DateTime ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId (DateTime dateTime, string sourceTimeZoneId, string destinationTimeZoneId);**
>
> dateTime - DateTime - The date and time to convert.
>
> sourceTimeZoneId - String - The identifier of the source time zone.
>
> destinationTimeZoneId - String - The **identifier** of the destination time zone.

Try this instead:

```
PS> $timestamp = [DateTime]::NowUtc

PS> [TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($timestamp, "UTC", (Get-TimeZone).Id)

07 May 2021 11:48:53
```

Comment: Good catch, I started writing an answer with `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo)` but it requires the date to be explicitly UTC (`Kind` property = `"utc"`) which I couldn't force onto a "parsed" DateTime...